Como crear una función que solicite al usuario que ingrese una letra y verifique si es una *"vocal" o una *"consonante"
Este es el código planteado, aunque aún no tengo claro como resolverlo
function isVocal(letra) {
  let vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
  if (letra === vocales) {
    console.log("vocal");
  } else {
    console.log("consonante");
  }
}
isVocal(p);


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Puedes usar la función includes para buscar si la letra ingresada se coincide con alguna vocal, esto para determinar si es vocal, de otra forma es consonante.


    function isVocal(letra) {
        let vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
        letra = letra.toLowerCase();
        //if (letra === vocales ){
        if (vocales.includes(letra)) {//* verifica si la letra ingresada es una vocal.
            console.log("vocal");
        } else {
            console.log("consonante");
        }
    }
    
    let letra = prompt("Ingresa una letra:");
    
    isVocal(letra);




Hay que hacer una validación para verificar que no sea número:
function isVocal(letra) {
        let vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
        if(typeof letra === 'number'){
            console.log("Es Número");
        }else if (vocales.includes(letra)) {
                console.log("vocal");
        } else {
            console.log("consonante");
        }
    }
    
    let letra = prompt("Ingresa una letra:");
    
    isVocal(letra);

